# Publish Angular App Alongside Web API to Azure

Tags: azure

I created an ASP.NET Core app with Angular as instructed via [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022). I'm publishing it to Azure using the GitHub Action support, which was generated by Azure and then I modified to get it to work. I've got it working for my app but only the API seems to publish, and at the designated endpoint URLs. This makes sense since I had to modify the workflow to indicate the API project directly. How can I publish the Angular app (in the UI project) to Azure as well with this same workflow?

Here is the repo for reference: https://github.com/rarDevelopment/rardk-web-dotnet
The workflow: https://github.com/rarDevelopment/rardk-web-dotnet/blob/main/.github/workflows/main_rardkweb.yml
and the API sample endpoint can be seen running here: https://rardkweb.azurewebsites.net/WeatherForecast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with a different approach, using this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022

From scratch, it was much easier because it got the app working locally and then the publish step also created the necessary Azure resources automatically.

Comment: But how? I followed these instructions as well to publish to remote IIS server, but when I do publish, only ASP.NET files are being copied to the remote machine. How do I get it to copy angular files as well?

Answer (score 0):

the Angular app will get published via `npm run build` , it says so also in the guide you linked, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022#publish-the-project)

> The publish process takes more time than it does for just an ASP.NET Core project, since the npm run build command gets invoked when publishing.

In dotnet [static files are stored](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#serve-static-files) within the project's [web root directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=linux#web-root).

Your angular project should be configured to publish the result of `npm run build` in the web root directory (www) of your dotnet project.

When the built Angular app is in the www directory, then you build/publish the dotnet project, which needs to be configured (see the guide examplecode) to serve static files.